# How can a fragment shader use the color values of the previously rendered frame?

Tags: opengl-es, glsl, shader, opengl-es-2.0, fragment-shader

I am learning to use shaders in OpenGL ES.

As an example: Here's my playground fragment shader which takes the current video frame and makes it grayscale:

```
varying highp vec2 textureCoordinate;

uniform sampler2D videoFrame;

void main() {
    highp vec4 theColor = texture2D(videoFrame, textureCoordinate);
    highp float avrg = (theColor[0] + theColor[1] + theColor[2]) / 3.0;
    theColor[0] = avrg; // r
    theColor[1] = avrg; // g
    theColor[2] = avrg; // b
    gl_FragColor = theColor;
}
```

`theColor` represents the current pixel. It would be cool to also get access to the previous pixel at this same coordinate.

For sake of curiousity, I would like to add or multiply the color of the current pixel to the color of the pixel in the previous render frame.

How could I keep the previous pixels around and pass them in to my fragment shader in order to do something with them?

Note: It's OpenGL ES 2.0 on the iPhone.

Comment: As Matias Valdenegro states below you need to render to an FBO. But when you do that and render using your shader it will be quite bright, you should divide by three instead of two to get the correct average. A way that is more often used when converting to greyscale use a weighted sum of the color components. See  http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/ref/rgb2gray.html for what weights that are good.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. Was a typo in my code.

Comment: And you should not add and divide at all in the first place. You should use the `dot` instrinsic function, which maps to an instruction that does both in one step, and much faster.

Comment: Thanks! What exactly do you mean by "dot intrinsic function"? Can you point out a resource or example?

Comment: I mean `dot(theColor.xyz, vec3(0.3333))`. The dot product multiplies two vectors, and then adds up the components. Which is exactly what you are doing, except it's a single 1-cycle instruction. See [dot](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/manglsl/xhtml/dot.xml)

Comment: @Damon: It _may_ be a "single 1-cycle instruction". It may also be 3 instructions (one vector multiply, two dependent adds). However, whatever it is, it will still be superior to his code. Or at worst, it will be no slower, so he should still do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to render the previous frame to a texture, using a Framebuffer Object (FBO), then you can read this texture in your fragment shader.

Comment: Can you give some examples or point out some good resources that cover this topic?

Answer (score -1):

The **dot intrinsic function** that *Damon* refers to is a code implementation of the mathematical dot product.  I'm not supremely familiar with OpenGL so I'm not sure what the exact function call is, but mathematically a dot product goes like this :

Given a `vector a` and a `vector b`, the `'dot' product a 'dot' b` produces a scalar result `c`:

```
c = a.x * b.x + a.y * b.y + a.z * b.z
```

Most modern graphics hardware (and CPUs, for that matter) are capable of performing this kind of operation in one pass.  In your particular case, you could compute your average easily with a dot product like so:

```
highp vec4 = (1/3, 1/3, 1/3, 0) //or zero
```

I always get the 4th component in homogeneous vectors and matrices mixed up for some reason.

```
highp float avg = theColor DOT vec4
```

This will **multiple each** component of theColor by `1/3` (and the 4th component by 0), and then **add them together**.